# Why is not Bech32 address selected as default in Bitcoin Core 0.16.0?

Tags: bitcoin-core, segregated-witness, p2sh, bech32-address

So, thankfully Bitcoin Core 0.16.0 came to us, general people.

But however, native segwit address Bech32 wasn't selected as default.

Is not it better to use a Bech32 address right away rather than P2SH segwit-wrapped address?

Comment: Can be selected in GUI environment, just check the box `Generate Bech32 address` on the receive tab.

Comment: @Willtech Oh right. I missed that. But the question still remains. Do you know why is not selected as default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bech32 Addresses is still not supported on the other platforms. There are many libraries even considering bech32 address as "invalid."

If I'm using `Bech32` address and asking someone who is using another platform to send me some bitcoin they may never be able to make the payment.

We need some time so it becomes supported everywhere.

Right now Blockchain.info, Electrum doesn't support bech32 address and they're highly used.

[image]